# How should I Query this in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a web app in which I show a series of posts based on this table schema (there are thousands of rows like this and other columns too (removed as not required for this question)) :-

```
+---------+----------+----------+
|   ID    |   COL1   |   COL2   |
+---------+----------+----------+
|   1     |    NULL  |   ----   |
|   2     |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   3     |    NULL  |   ----   |
|   4     |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   5     |    NULL  |   NULL   |
|   6     |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   7     |    NULL  |   ----   |
|   8     |    ---   |   NULL   |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

And I use this query :-

```
SELECT * from `TABLE` WHERE `COL1` IS NOT NULL AND `COL2` IS NULL ORDER BY `COL1`;
```

And the resultant result set I get is like:-

```
+---------+----------+----------+
|   ID    |   COL1   |   COL2   |
+---------+----------+----------+
|   12    |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   1     |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   6     |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   8     |    ---   |   NULL   |
|  11     |    ---   |   NULL   |
|  13     |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   5     |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   9     |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   17    |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   21    |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   23    |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   4     |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   32    |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   58    |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   61    |    ---   |   NULL   |
|   43    |    ---   |   NULL   |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

Notice that the IDs column is jumbled thanks to the order by clause.

I have proper indexes to optimize these queries.
 Now, let me explain the real problem. I have a lazy-load kind of functionality in my web-app. So, I display around 10 posts per page by using a `LIMIT 10` after the query for the first page.

We are good till here. But, the real problem comes when I have to load the second page. What do I query now? I do not want the posts to be repeated. And there are new posts coming up almost every 15 seconds which make them go on top(by top I literally mean the first row) of the resultset(I do not want to display these latest posts in the second or third pages but they alter the resultset size so I cannot use `LIMIT 10,10` for the 2nd page and so on as the posts will be repeated.).

Now, all I know is the last ID of the post that I displayed. Say `21` here. So, I want to display the posts of IDs `23,4,32,58,61,43` (refer to the resultset table above). Now, do I load all the rows without using the `LIMIT` clause and display 10 ids occurring after the id `21`. But for that I will have to interate over thousands of useless rows.But, I cannot use a `LIMIT` clause for the 2nd,3rd... pages that is for sure. Also, the IDs are jumbled, so I can definitely not use `WHERE ID>...`. So, where do we go now?

Comment: Since your `COL1` is sortable, how about remembering the latest record of `COL1` in each request, and in next page load `WHERE COL1>?`?

Comment: @Passerby, I have already thought of that. But, `COL1`  has many identical rows. Actually, `COL1` is a timestamp and many rows may have the same timestamp (in my resultset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm..
I thought for a while and came up with 2 solutions. :-

1. To store the Ids of the post already displayed and query `WHERE ID NOT IN(id1,id2,...)`. But, that would cost you extra memory. And if the user loads 100 pages and the ids are in 100000s then a single GET request would not be able to handle it. At least not in all browsers. A POST request can be used.
2. Alter the way you display posts from `COL1`. I don't know if this would be a good way for you. But, it can save you bandwith and make your code cleaner. It may also be a better way. I would suggest this :- `SELECT * from TABLE where COL1 IS NOT NULL AND COL2 IS NULL AND Id>.. ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10,10`. This can affect the way you display your posts by leaps and bounds. But, as you said in your comments that you check if a post meets a criteria and change the COL1 from NULL to the current timestammp, I guess that the newer the posts the, the more above you want to display them. It's just an idea.

Comment: I have already tried the first method before. But did not find it very doable. But, I think that I can give your second method a try. Thanks +1

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question correctly, but here's how I think I would do it:

- Add a timestamp column to your table, let's call it `date_added`
- When displaying the **first page**, use your query as-is (with `LIMIT 10`) and hang on to the timestamp of the most recent record; let's call it `last_date_added`.
- For the **2nd, 3rd and subsequent pages**, modify your query to filter out all records with `date_added > last_date_added`, and use `LIMIT 10, 10`, `LIMIT 20, 10`, `LIMIT 30, 10` and so on.

This will have the effect of freezing your resultset in time, and resetting it every time the first page is accessed.

**Notes:**

- Depending on the ordering of your resultset, you might need a separate query to obtain the `last_date_added`. Alternatively, you could just cut off at the current time, i.e. the time when the first page was accessed.
- If your IDs are sequential, you could use the same trick with the ID.

Comment: It's funny that the column `COL1` is a timestamp. But, unfortunately as I mentioned in the comment above, it is not quite unique as many rows share the same timestamp. I check if a post meets a criteria and change the `COL1` from NULL to the current timestammp. So, if many posts meet the criteria, they are of the same timestamp.

Comment: @user4647309 So why not add an additional `date_added` timestamp that gets set when the record is inserted? If you use microsecond precision, it should be fairly unique. Or, as I said, if your IDs are sequential, before executing the query for the first page, you could get the highest ID and use that to freeze the resultset for subsequent pages.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I think the problem is that sorting by `COL1` would "ruin" the sorting order of `ID` or any similar thing: with the same `COL1` this may help, but a `WHERE \`ID\`>?` would also filter out some result that have higher `COL1` but lower `ID`.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks for your feedback. I think I still haven't completely understood what OP is actually trying to achieve. However, it seems that an answer was accepted, so I'm glad that someone did :-)

Answer (score 1):

I assume new posts will be added with a higher ID than the current max ID right? So couldn't you just run your query and grab the current max ID. Then when you query for page 2 do the same query but with "ID < max_id". This should give you the same result set as your page 1 query because any new rows will have ID > max_id. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
ORDER BY `COL1`,`ID`;
```

This would always put IDs in order. This will let you use:

```
LIMIT 10,10
```

for your second page.